# Restore original layout of views within a perspective in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

If you are an Eclipse user, you have had this happen to you for sure:

You accidentally click on a view within a perspective and move the mouse and then that messes up the entire layout within that perspetive that you are used to.

I want to know if it is possible to restore the original layout of views within a perspective once an accidental change like that happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective...

Comment: Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective