# Set Views to default

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore original layout of views within a perspective in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848477/restore-original-layout-of-views-within-a-perspective-in-eclipse)

I use Eclipse IDE ,Version: Helios Service for android development(ADT installed). Somehow my views have been changed. I want to set everything(my views) to default. How do I do that.

Comment: You mean to say eclipse views ?

Comment: Window -> Open Perspective -> Java